# Remove the cover of bathroom light so I can change the bulb

Tags: electrical

[image]I need to change the light bulb in my bathroom but I couldn’t remove the plastic cover.  I tried to attach an image but it says the file was too large.

Comment: Then reduce the size of the image.

Comment: Are there any thumbscrews along the perimeter of the light base?

Comment: It looks like a light that is held up with clips. You just need to pull down firmly with a good hold on the fixture.